# Display Values of a row after delete

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a `delete` button in my site that deletes a row in a table.

After the row is deleted, the user is redirect to another page.

Is it possible to display the deleted row values in the redirected page? 
thank you!

```
        <table class="table table-striped b-t b-light">
        <thead>
            <tr>

                <th style="text-align: center">User Name</th>
                 <th style="text-align: center">User Last Name</th>
                 <th style="text-align: center">Email</th>
                  <th style="text-align: center">Password</th>
                   <th style="text-align: center">User Type</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">Edit</th>
                    <th style="text-align: center">Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
          <?php foreach ($ulistq as $urule) : ?>
        <tbody>

        <th style="text-align: center"><?= $urule['u_name'] ?></th>
        <th style="text-align: center"><?= $urule['u_lastname'] ?></th>
        <th style="text-align: center"><?= $urule['u_email'] ?></th>
        <th style="text-align: center"><?= $urule['u_password'] ?></th>
        <th style="text-align: center"><?= $urule['u_rule'] ?></th>
        <td style="text-align: center"> <a href="useredit.php?eid=<?= $urule['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-info active">Edit</a> </td>
          <td style="text-align: center"> <a href="userdel.php?eid=<?= $urule['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-info active">Delete</a> </td> 
        </tbody>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Provide code samples for better answers

Comment: yes it is possible to pass the values to the redirected page, but firstly provide your code to get appropriate answer

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Does userdel.php really DELETE, or just 'hide' the 'deleted' row?

Comment: @Dror Shalit, if you find my answer good, I will appreciate if you thumb it up and select it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the option of adding the values to the redirect URL and extract them in the redirected page.

So instead of this redirect:

```
redirect to www.example.com/afterdelete
```

You can do

```
redirect to www.example.com/afterdelete?value1=1&value2=2
```

This option can be done both in the server side, as well as the client side.

You will need your `afterDelete` page to extract these values and to display them